# Jest mocking a function with hooks fails

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, next.js, enzyme

I'm using `nextJs` and `jest` `enzyme` for testing of component. I have a component file like below, where I get `items` array from props and loop to it calling `setRef` inside `useEffect`.

```
[itemRefs, setItemRefs] = React.useState([]);

setRef = () => {
     const refArr = [];
     items.forEach(item => {
        const setItemRef = RefItem => {
             refArr.push(RefItem)
        }

       if(item && item.rendItem){
           item.rendItem = item.rendItem.bind(null, setItemRef);
       }
   }
   setItemRefs(refArr);
}

React.useEffect(() => {
   setRef();
},[])
```

My test file is like below :

```
const items = [
       {
          original: 'mock-picture-link',
          thumbnail: 'mock-thumb-link',
          renderItem: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ props: { children: {} } })
       }
      ];
     
       beforeEach(() => {
         setItemRefs = jest.fn(),
         jest.spyOn(React, 'useEffect').mockImplementationOnce(fn => fn());
       })
       

    it('mocks item references', ()=>{
        jest.spyOn(React, 'useState').mockImplementationOnce(() => [items, setItemRefs]);
        wrapper = shallow(<Component />).dive();
        expect(setItemRefs).toHaveBeenCalledWith(items);
    })
```

The test case fails with expected as `items` array BUT received a blank array. The `console.log` inside `if(item && item.rendItem)` works but `console.log` inside `const setItemRef = RefItem => {...` doesn't work I doubt the `.bind` is not getting mocked in jest.

Any help would be fine.

Comment: I didn't see you pass `items` as a component prop.

Comment: pass `items` in test?

Comment: You said you "get items array from props". But there is no `items` prop when shallow renders the component. Please provide the minimal, complete code. Don't know where `items` come from in your code.